# How to clear image caches on the flatlist?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I got a product list page. Which is mainly consist of `flatList` items.
and this **product list will change** according to the props passed to the component.

When user comes into the page first time. The list is showing fine. let take It as `LISTA`

But when user comes into the page second time. The flat list item will show old items images for a moment which is images from listA before changes into the new one which is `LISTB`

What I don't understand is that I do put a loading screen when api is calling the list and change into `setLoading false` in finally block. So why the images are not changed into the new one before loading screen comes off?

Eg Code

```
useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true)
  axios.get('pList')
 .then((res) => {setProductList(res.data) })
 .catch((e) =>. {})
 .finally(() => setLoading(false))
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be re-render image from everytime. You need to cache image in default application or device memory. Best way is the FastImage for lazyloading.

```
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image'
    
<FastImage
        style={styles.image}
        source={{
          uri: YOUR_IMAGE_URL,
          priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        }}
        resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

pass `navigation` as props and detect change in navigation state. and set list to empty while unfocused

```
export default function ProductScreen({navigation}: any) {

useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      setLoading(true)
      axios.get('pList')
     .then((res) => {setProductList(res.data) })
     .catch((e) =>. {})
     .finally(() => setLoading(false))
    });

    return () => {
        unsubscribe,
        setProductList([])
    }
 }, [navigation]);

}
```